# rbindlist a list column of data.frames and select unique values

Tags: r, list, data.table, aggregate, rbindlist

I have a data.table 'DT' with a column ('col2') that is a list of data frames:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(col1 = c('A','A','B'),
                 col2 = list(data.frame(colA = c(1,3,54, 23), 
                                        colB = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "hh")),
                             data.frame(colA =c(23, 1),
                                       colB = c("hh", "aa")), 
                             data.frame(colA = 1,
                                       colB = "aa")))

> DT
   col1         col2
1:    A <data.frame>
2:    A <data.frame>
3:    B <data.frame>

>> DT$col2
[[1]]
  colA colB
1    1   aa
2    3   bb
3   54   cc
4   23   hh

[[2]]
  colA colB
1   23   hh
2    1   aa

[[3]]
  colA colB
1    1   aa
```

Each data.frame in col2 has two columns colA and colB.
I'd like to have a data.table output that binds each *unique* row of those data.frames based on col1 of DT.
I guess it's like using `rbindlist` in an aggregate function of the data.table.

This is the desired output:

```
> #desired output
> output
   colA colB col1
1:    1   aa    A
2:    3   bb    A
3:   54   cc    A
4:   23   hh    A
5:    1   aa    B
```

The dataframe of the second row of DT (`DT[2, col2]`) has duplicate entries, and only unique entries are desired for each unique col1.

I tried the following and I get an error.

```
desired_output <- DT[, lapply(col2, function(x) unique(rbindlist(x))), by = col1]
# Error in rbindlist(x) : 
#   Item 1 of list input is not a data.frame, data.table or list
```

This 'works', though not desired output:

```
unique(rbindlist(DT$col2))
   colA colB
1:    1   aa
2:    3   bb
3:   54   cc
4:   23   hh
```

Is there anyway to use `rbindlist` in an aggregate function of a data.table?

Comment: `unique(tidyr::unnest(DT[, c("col1","col2")]))`

Comment: Can even shorten to: `unique(tidyr::unnest(DT))`

Comment: I didn't read the q thoroughly but your desired output is `unique(DT[, rbindlist(setNames(col2, col1), id="col1")])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group `by` 'col1', run `rbindlist` on 'col2':

```
unique(DT[ , rbindlist(col2), by = col1]) # trimmed thanks to @snoram
#    col1 colA colB
# 1:    A    1   aa
# 2:    A    3   bb
# 3:    A   54   cc
# 4:    A   23   hh
# 5:    B    1   aa
```

Comment: Neat! And can also be shortened: `DT[ , rbindlist(col2), by = col1]`

Comment: And maybe `DT[, unique(rbindlist(col2)), by = col1]`

Answer (score 2):

> only unique entries are desired for each unique `col1`

If you add a column for `col1`, the expression above means "unique entries" (unconditional on columns).

Henrik's answer is one way to keep `col1`. Another is:

```
unique(DT[, rbindlist(setNames(col2, col1), id="col1")])
```

I guess this should be more efficient than

```
bycols = "col1"
unique(DT[, rbindlist(col2), by=bycols])   # Henrik's
```

though the extension to either (1) `col1` not being a character column (hence suitable for `setNames`) or (2) having multiple `by=` columns is not so obvious. For either of these cases, I would make an `.id` column equal to row numbers of `DT` then copy them over:

```
bycols = "col1"
res = unique(DT[, rbindlist(col2, id="DT_row")])
res[, (bycols) := DT[DT_row, ..bycols]]
```

To put those columns first/leftmost, I think `setcolorder(res, bycols)` should work, but am on too old a data.table version to see it do so.

There's also [an open issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2146) for a `tidyr::unnest`-like function.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something hackish like this:

```
nDT <- cbind(rbindlist(DT[[2]]), col1 = rep(DT[[1]], sapply(DT[[2]], nrow)))
nDT[!duplicated(nDT)]
   colA colB col1
1:    1   aa    A
2:    3   bb    A
3:   54   cc    A
4:   23   hh    A
5:    1   aa    B
```

Or using tidyr (Inspired by PKumar's comment):

```
unique(tidyr::unnest(DT))
```

Or more generalisable base R:

```
names(DT[[2]]) <- DT[[1]]
ndf <- do.call(rbind, DT[[2]])
ndf$col1 <- substr(row.names(ndf), 1, 1)
unique(ndf)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
DT1<-apply(DT, 1, function(x){cbind(col1=x$col1,x$col2)})
unique(rbindlist(DT1))
#   col1 colA colB
#1:    A    1   aa
#2:    A    3   bb
#3:    A   54   cc
#4:    A   23   hh
#5:    B    1   aa
```