# How to convert the type of a column stored in a data.frame within a data.table column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a list of `data.frames` stored within a `data.table` column:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- structure(list(display_name = c("Entity 1", "Entity 2"), reporting_currency = c("USD", 
                                      "USD"), fund_metrics = list(structure(list(metric_category = c("Partners' Capital", 
     "Partners' Capital", "Partners' Capital", "Partners' Capital", 
     "Partners' Capital", "Partners' Capital", "Partners' Capital", 
     "Partners' Capital", "Partners' Capital", "Partners' Capital", 
     "Partners' Capital", "Partners' Capital", "Partners' Capital", 
     "Partners' Capital", "Partners' Capital"), labeled_as = c("Total Partners' Capital", 
               "Total Partners' Capital", "Total Partners' Capital", "Total Partners' Capital", 
               "Total Partners' Capital", "Total Partners' Capital", "Total Partners' Capital", 
               "Total Partners' Capital", "Total Partners' Capital", "Total Partners' Capital", 
               "Total Partners' Capital", "Total Partners' Capital", "Total Partners' Capital", 
               "Total Partners' Capital", "Total Partners' Capital"), reporting_sign = c(1L, 
                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), value = c(589933611, 
            5168, 49489, 49686, 59470, 72353, 232288, 
            28767, 1190516, 17154, 372091, 30719, 3472, 
            12634, 9528), date = c("2020-03-31", "2019-12-31", 
                                             "2019-09-30", "2019-06-30", "2020-06-30", "2020-09-30", "2020-12-31", 
                                             "2021-03-31", "2022-06-30", "2022-03-31", "2021-12-31", "2021-09-30", 
                                             "2021-06-30", "2022-09-30", "2022-12-31")), row.names = c(NA, 
       15L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(metric_category = c("Partners' Capital", 
                       "Partners' Capital", "Partners' Capital", "Partners' Capital", 
                       "Partners' Capital", "Partners' Capital", "Partners' Capital", 
                       "Partners' Capital", "Partners' Capital", "Partners' Capital", 
                       "Partners' Capital"), labeled_as = c("Total Partners' Capital", 
            "Total Partners' Capital", "Total Partners' Capital", "Total Partners' Capital", 
            "Total Partners' Capital", "Total Partners' Capital", "Total Partners' Capital", 
            "Total Partners' Capital", "Total Partners' Capital", "Total Partners' Capital", 
            "Total Partners' Capital"), reporting_sign = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), value = c(1130L, 173202L, 
  53830L, 66257L, 15L, 67968L, 6639L, 1097127L, 
  9499L, 5211L, 40217L), date = c("2020-06-30", "2020-09-30", 
                                             "2020-12-31", "2019-12-31", "2019-06-30", "2019-09-30", "2021-03-31", 
                                             "2020-03-31", "2021-12-31", "2022-03-31", "2022-06-30")), row.names = c(NA, 
                     11L), class = "data.frame"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", 
                                      "data.frame"))
```

This is how it looks:

```
 DT
   display_name reporting_currency       fund_metrics
1:     Entity 1                USD <data.frame[15x5]>
2:     Entity 2                USD <data.frame[11x5]>
```

My desired output is to expand the `data.frames` and keep the information in columns `display_name` and `reporting_currency` and store this all in one `data.table`. The following loop achieves this result:

```
resDT <- as.data.table(DT[1, fund_metrics])
resDT[, "Name":=list(DT[1, display_name])]
resDT[, "CUR" :=list(DT[1, reporting_currency])]
for (i in 2:nrow(DT)) {
  
  intDT <- as.data.table(DT[i, fund_metrics])
  if (nrow(intDT)>0) {
    intDT[, "Name":=list(DT[i, display_name])]
    intDT[, "CUR" :=list(DT[i, reporting_currency])]  
  }
  resDT <- rbind(resDT, intDT)
  
}
resDT
      metric_category              labeled_as reporting_sign     value       date     Name CUR
 1: Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital              1 589933611 2020-03-31 Entity 1 USD
 2: Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital              1      5168 2019-12-31 Entity 1 USD
 3: Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital              1     49489 2019-09-30 Entity 1 USD
 4: Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital              1     49686 2019-06-30 Entity 1 USD
 5: Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital              1     59470 2020-06-30 Entity 1 USD
...
```

This didn't feel very `data.table` efficient to me and I found a much better way of doing it on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51038271/rbindlist-a-list-column-of-data-frames-and-select-unique-values).

However, this solution doesn't work for me because the columns in the `data.frames` do not have the same types. I get the following error:

```
DT[, rbindlist(fund_metrics),by=list(display_name, reporting_currency)]
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , rbindlist(fund_metrics), by = list(display_name,  : 
  Column 4 of result for group 2 is type 'integer' but expecting type 'double'. Column types must be consistent for each group.
```

I don't quite understand why `rbindlist` doesn't coerce the integer to double, as the help page reads:

> If column i does not have the same type in each of the list items; e.g, the column is integer in item 1 while others are numeric, they are coerced to the highest type.

I assume double is something else than integer/numeric, but not sure. My question though is if there is an efficient way to change the column types in the `data.frames` nested within the `data.table` before using `rbindlist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `unnest` from package `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
DT %>%
  unnest(fund_metrics)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 26 × 7
   display_name reporting_currency metric_category   labeled_as   reporting_sign
   <chr>        <chr>              <chr>             <chr>                 <int>
 1 Entity 1     USD                Partners' Capital Total Partn…              1
 2 Entity 1     USD                Partners' Capital Total Partn…              1
 3 Entity 1     USD                Partners' Capital Total Partn…              1
 4 Entity 1     USD                Partners' Capital Total Partn…              1
 5 Entity 1     USD                Partners' Capital Total Partn…              1
 6 Entity 1     USD                Partners' Capital Total Partn…              1
 7 Entity 1     USD                Partners' Capital Total Partn…              1
 8 Entity 1     USD                Partners' Capital Total Partn…              1
 9 Entity 1     USD                Partners' Capital Total Partn…              1
10 Entity 1     USD                Partners' Capital Total Partn…              1
# ℹ 16 more rows
# ℹ 2 more variables: value <dbl>, date <chr>
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

---

If you would like to load `data.table` and use `rbindlist` only, you can use `rbindlist` like below (should use it **without** `by`)

```
copy(DT)[
  ,
  id := .I
][
  ,
  fund_metrics := NULL
][DT[
  ,
  rbindlist(fund_metrics, idcol = "id")
], on = "id"][
  ,
  id := NULL
][]
```

which gives

```
    display_name reporting_currency   metric_category              labeled_as
 1:     Entity 1                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
 2:     Entity 1                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
 3:     Entity 1                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
 4:     Entity 1                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
 5:     Entity 1                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
 6:     Entity 1                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
 7:     Entity 1                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
 8:     Entity 1                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
 9:     Entity 1                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
10:     Entity 1                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
11:     Entity 1                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
12:     Entity 1                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
13:     Entity 1                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
14:     Entity 1                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
15:     Entity 1                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
16:     Entity 2                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
17:     Entity 2                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
18:     Entity 2                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
19:     Entity 2                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
20:     Entity 2                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
21:     Entity 2                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
22:     Entity 2                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
23:     Entity 2                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
24:     Entity 2                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
25:     Entity 2                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
26:     Entity 2                USD Partners' Capital Total Partners' Capital
    display_name reporting_currency   metric_category              labeled_as
    reporting_sign     value       date
 1:              1 589933611 2020-03-31
 2:              1      5168 2019-12-31
 3:              1     49489 2019-09-30
 4:              1     49686 2019-06-30
 5:              1     59470 2020-06-30
 6:              1     72353 2020-09-30
 7:              1    232288 2020-12-31
 8:              1     28767 2021-03-31
 9:              1   1190516 2022-06-30
10:              1     17154 2022-03-31
11:              1    372091 2021-12-31
12:              1     30719 2021-09-30
13:              1      3472 2021-06-30
14:              1     12634 2022-09-30
15:              1      9528 2022-12-31
16:              1      1130 2020-06-30
17:              1    173202 2020-09-30
18:              1     53830 2020-12-31
19:              1     66257 2019-12-31
20:              1        15 2019-06-30
21:              1     67968 2019-09-30
22:              1      6639 2021-03-31
23:              1   1097127 2020-03-31
24:              1      9499 2021-12-31
25:              1      5211 2022-03-31
26:              1     40217 2022-06-30
    reporting_sign     value       date
```

Comment: Thanks, that works well. As I don't expect huge data set, I actually like using the `tidyr` solution and then transform it again to a `data.table`.